# Using analyze index [INDEX] validate structure in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to get the index stats from all user index in an oracle database, I notice that "analyze index [INDEX] validate structure" can be used one at the time, so I'm trying to do it on a pl/sql procedure as follows:

```
DECLARE
    aux index_stats%ROWTYPE;
    CURSOR names
    IS
        SELECT index_name 
        FROM user_indexes
        WHERE table_owner = 'STUDENT';
BEGIN
    FOR each IN names
    LOOP
        analyze index each.index_name validate structure; --This line
        select name
        into aux
        from index_stats;
        dbms_output.put_line( aux.index_name);
        -- Do something with index_stats info
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

So every loop the table index_stats updates with the next user index, but that doesn't work. This error is displayed:

**Encountered the symbol "INDEX" when expecting one of the following:
:= . ( @ % ;**

Is there a way I can use **Using analyze index [INDEX] validate structure** in PL/SQL or I just need to find another way to do it?

I didn't find anything about using analyze index in pl/sql procedure. 
I found the dbms_stats.gather_index_stats function, but it doesn't work with stats_index table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need tro wrap that line up with `execute immediate`

`execute immediate  'analyze index '||each.index_name||' validate structure';`

because that command is neither a DML nor a SELECT statement.

And remove this statement

```
select name
  into aux
  from index_stats
```

which has no sense, the index names are already been returned.

Then print directly the name of the index by

`dbms_output.put_line( each.index_name );`